# Change users in secured Access application

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2003 application set up with user-level security.  Is it possible, after opening and logging into Access, to be able to change users?  Ideally, my client would like to be able to click a button (or something) and be prompted for a different user login.  I told him I didn't think it was possible without closing and re-opening Access, but if it is it'll make me look good.  That's always important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  I've seen this asked and answered by folks in the Microsoft newsgroups who know Access user level security far better than I do.